# How to get chanel cover using API V3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I have this js code

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&id=UCAeWo3hCZSmoEaM-vJyzsfg&key=KEY', function(data) {
var chBnrUrl = data.items[0].brandingSettings.image.bannerImageUrl;
alert(chBnrUrl);
 });
```

But I do not know Why the logo is not fetched in the alert ?

Answer (score 1):

[Channel.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) returns a [channel resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource) however not all of the information is public.  Some of the fields may only be returned for the owner of the channel.  You appear to be using an api key which is only going to return the public information about the channel.   If you are the owner of the channel you should use oauth2 and authenticate this request then you should see all of the information.

Request:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&id=UCAeWo3hCZSmoEaM-vJyzsfg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/eeWwfxY-1l2O08f8ZaRnNotNxAw\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {


   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/AsC3_c59Ey-DtR_xdRsD6S1QtDg\"",
   "id": "UCAeWo3hCZSmoEaM-vJyzsfg",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "G & Kids Future",
    "description": "• Welcome all the guests channel G & Kids Future! ♥\n\n• G & Kids Future - Youtube channel for children, for girls and boys. This is the channel for all kids searching for entertainment. Enjoy the channel and subscribe to get to the newest updates!\n\n• Thank you for visiting our channel !!!",
    "customUrl": "gkidsfuture92",
    "publishedAt": "2016-01-07T04:47:47.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-HBvDBX_Fwjw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/aCgthXWsd-g/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
      "width": 88,
      "height": 88
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-HBvDBX_Fwjw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/aCgthXWsd-g/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
      "width": 240,
      "height": 240
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-HBvDBX_Fwjw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/aCgthXWsd-g/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
      "width": 800,
      "height": 800
     }
    },
    "localized": {
     "title": "G & Kids Future",
     "description": "• Welcome all the guests channel G & Kids Future! ♥\n\n• G & Kids Future - Youtube channel for children, for girls and boys. This is the channel for all kids searching for entertainment. Enjoy the channel and subscribe to get to the newest updates!\n\n• Thank you for visiting our channel !!!"
    }
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "257607760",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "895691",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "150"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

you are not seeing `data.items[0].brandingSettings.image.bannerImageUrl;` becouse brandingSettings is not part of the response test [tryme](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252Cstatistics&id=UCAeWo3hCZSmoEaM-vJyzsfg&_h=1&)

Comment: I made mistake, the right link is
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics,brandingSettings&id=key'

Comment: you are still using an API key so it won't change it's not public data authenticate your user and try again